# Firebase Custom Claims in ReactJS || Showing Admin UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a login system in my React App, it should show different UI (at the moment a different navbar) depending on whether a user has an admin custom token, user custom token or the user isn't logged in.

Currently, the admin user gets the token but I'm not sure how to change the UI depending on what token the user has.

CODE:

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Header.scss';
import PublicNavigation from '../PublicLinks/PublicLinks';
import AdminNavigation from '../AdminLinks/AdminLinks';
import UserNavigation from '../UserLinks/UserLinks';
import SignUpButton from '../SignUpButton/SignUpButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LogOut from '../LogOut/LogOut'

const Header = (props) => {
    // Firebase Login Check -- This is what changes the navigation based on whether the user is logged in or not!
    const {auth } = props;
    // console.log(auth);
    const nav = auth.uid ? <UserNavigation/> : <PublicNavigation/> 
    const button = auth.uid ? <LogOut/> : <SignUpButton/>

    return (
      <div className = "Header">

            <div className = "Logo">
                {/* Company Logo */}
                <h1 className = "CompanyName"> Logo.</h1>
            </div>

            {/* These are the login , signup and log out buttons */}
            { button }

            <div className = "Navigation"> 

            { nav }

            </div>
        
           

            
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)
```

functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // get user and add admin custom claim
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      admin: true
    })
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin.`
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your logic seems right. You already done the most of the job.

All you have to do is figure out who is logged in. Admin or others?
I see that you have an `auth` object, i think you can understand which type of user logged in. Once you got that information your code will work properly.

`const nav = auth.uid ? <UserNavigation/> : <PublicNavigation/>`

I am not sure if `auth` has `userType` field but there must be something like that.

Example:

```
const Nav = () => {
   if(auth.userType === "admin")
    return <AdminNav/>
   else if(auth.userType === "user")
    return <UserNav/>
   else
    return <PublicNav/>
}
```

Then you can use it as `<Nav/>` in your render function.

A very basic example below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hmjkmq?file=src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll have a play around with it